# How To Only Restrict PHP5/Apache to Send Mail Only To Local Users

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, sendmail, spam, php5

I need some help. I am running lastest stable Ubuntu which hosts Apache/PHP5 and also delivers email. I host some WordPress sites for other users and have been waging a war for months now combatting attackers who find bad permissions on directories and use that to upload php scripts to send spam through the server.

I of course am taking steps to automate security of WordPress but would also like to knock out PHP5/Apache's ability to send mail to any address not locally deliverable.

I am configuring a new server to do this on. I will be running the latest version of MailScanner with a choice of Sendmail or Postfix. This would specifically be directed at locking down the wwwdata user to only send locally.

I have already setup PHP5 mail logging but need to take this a step further because my hosting provider goes draconian when spam starts flowing. So far I have not had any luck finding answers via Google. Only thing I have found so far involves either disabling PHP's mail function or to log, review, firewall out IPs and delete offending scripts. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes postfix mta.

In php.ini add:

```
mail.add_x_header = 1
```

In /etc/main.cf add:

```
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks.pcre
```

Content of /etc/postfix/header_checks.pcre

```
if /X-PHP-Originating-Script.*/
!/To:[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+(@(localdomain1.com|localdomain2.com))?$/ REJECT PHP Mail is only allowed to submit mail for local delivery.
endif
```

The regex used here covers commonly used characters in the local part of email addresses, but does not cover every valid character as per RFC, YMMV.